# Probability of not get 1 after rolling a dice 20 times?

Tags: probability, dice

When rolled a dice 20 times, what is the probability of not getting a 1.

My though is since 5/6 ^ 20, but it doesnt seem right.

Comment: Why doesn't (5/6)^20 sound right?

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability of getting a $1$ on a single roll? Presumably, $1/6$.

What is the probability of **not** getting a $1$, then? $1-1/6$, or, equivalently, $5/6$.

Rolls are independent, so if you wanted to find the probability of events across rolls that don't depend on each other, you can just multiply the probability of each roll.

Thus, you're right: the probability is $(5/6)^{20}$.